# How to remove the "You are running an old version of the launcher" message in the Minecraft Launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I hate the new 2.0 Launcher design so i use the old one but there is always this message. Is there a way to remove it without using the new Launcher?[image]

Comment: I use the old launcher too.  That happened to me when I used the newer one, then used the older one afterward.  Try deleting the new launcher or just not opening it again.

Comment: Can't you just ignore the message? Or is it actually causing a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you are running the game on windows. Do not run the minecraft.exe file. minecraft.exe has a hardcoded bootstrap version number (5 I believe) and launcher will show the warning you mentioned for any bootstrap version below 100 if your OS is windows 8 and above.

Instead

1. create a shortcut to `%appdata%\.minecraft\launcher.jar`
2. Rename your existing `Minecraft.exe` to `minecraft.dll` so you don't run it again. this way you can keep the icon too.
3. modify shortcut you created in item 1 and change its icon to `minecraft.dll` created in item 2
4. run the game using the new shortcut and message will not showup

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to disable it, it is a warning that the application is outdated and not recommended anymore.  It may become unstable later on, so upgrading is a good idea.  While the new launcher might not be your favorite, it does everything the old one can and more.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend using [Multi MC](https://multimc.org/) (multimc.org)

It makes it very easy to set up separate versions of MC, and it also makes  [Forge](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/) mods easy to install if you are into mods.

Comment: Your link text seems to have a typo... Multi MC (couldn't edit since it was only a 1 character change...)

Comment: @Phil DD - I listed the url.